# Troubles with Delphi TcomPort and RS485

Tags: serial-port, delphi-7, rs485, tcomport

I am trying to communicate with SMC LEC6 Servo motor controller via Delphi 7-TComPort Library. I have read related questions [TComPort and Modbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276860/tcomport-and-modbus-rtu). My question is if I want to send a massage containing 8 bytes, how can I specify the stop-bit/start-bit values ? and Do I need to send each byte as a packet and the stop-bit separately or it will be done automatically by the library ?

Answer (score 0):

The start bit cannot be selected and this bit will be added to each byte automatically by your RS485 or RS232 hardware.

The stop bit type you may select in the component properties (e.g. 1 stop bit). This bit will be added automatically too.